# Logback appender rolling policy without a maxIndex value?

Tags: java, logback

I need to make sure one of my appenders never deletes any of the log files that it creates. Is there a way to rollover a file without setting a max number of log files allowed? If I leave out the `maxIndex`, does it default to some internal `maxIndex` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one logback-RollingPolicy which uses the `maxIndex`, and that is the `FixedWindowRollingPolicy`. It is **specifically designed to limit the amount of old files** kept on the system and the upper bound for `maxIndex` is 20.

The solution to keeping files indefinitely is simple then: **Use a different RollingPolicy**

A good candidate would be the [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy). It will allow you to - for example - roll over your logfile every day, possibly with compression. And so long as you do not specify the **optional** `maxHistory` property, it will never delete any of your archived logs.